# Monaco editor - Follow link hook

Tags: monaco-editor

Fellow coders,

I'm having a hard time to find a hook into the 'ctrl+click' (follow link) editor option.

On the demo page the link is opened in a new tab:
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html

After a thorough google search which came up with nothing I searched through the api but only found the context actions which do not include the follow link or ctrl+click action.

I would like to parse the filepath and fire some custom methods of my own instead of opening in a new tab.

Any of you guys found a clue where to add/modify the behavoir?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any news on this ? thanks!

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: Any news on this issue? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [IOpenerService's Open](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/platform/opener/common/opener.ts#L111) method, something like this:

```
var openerService = {
    open: function (resource, options) {
        // do something here, resource will contain the Uri
    }
};

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'),
    {
        automaticLayout: true, language: 'plaintext'
    },
    {
        openerService: openerService
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a better way to do this other than hooking `window.open` and checking the stack trace. Not ideal, but it works.

```js
const realopen = window.open;
function openShim(url?: string | URL, target?: string, features?: string) {
    const calledFromMonaco = new Error().stack?.includes("windowOpenNoOpener");
    if (calledFromMonaco) {
        return null;
    }
    return realopen(url, target, features);
}
window.open = openShim;
```